# Controls hide on view page in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using below code on the new.html.erb then it shows text field and button "Search" on the view page:

```
    <table> 
           <tr>
               <td align="center">
                  <%= text_field :tf_Company,placeholder: "Company" %>
               </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="button">
                      <%= button_to "Search", {}, { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
   </table>
```

But when I add `form_for(:search)` on new.html.erb, like below:

```
<% form_for(:search) do |f| %>
    <table> 
           <tr>
               <td align="center">
                  <%= f.text_field :tf_Company,placeholder: "Company" %>
               </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="button">
                      <%= f.submit "Search", { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
   </table>
<% end %>
```

then it would not show text field and button on view page, Kindly suggest me where I make mistake,
Waiting for your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for(:search) do |f| %>
```

You are missing = before form_for

Comment: @Hassan, please check what abhijit said. You've not done it in your code.